# Java - Retrofit 2 requests good practices

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I'm currently using retrofit for an Android application.
It is pretty new to me, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle simple requests without getting messy.

My client is communicating with my server using JSON (retrofit's JacksonConverter). 
So for now, I ended up doing something like this:

```
public interface MyWebService {

    class RequestLogin {
        public String email;
        public String hash;

        public RequestLogin(String email, String hash) {
            this.email = email;
            this.hash = hash;
        }
    }

    @POST("/login")
    Call<String> login(@Body RequestLogin body);

}

public void someFunction() {
    Call<String> call = serviceInstance.login(new RequestLogin("some_mail", "some_hash"));
}
```

here you can see that my `/login` route takes a simple JSON:

```
{
  "email": "some_email_here",
  "hash": "some_passwd_hash_here"
}
```

and returns a simple string in the body.

It is not that bad but I'm afraid things can get messy with time.

Is creating an object the only way to use JSON inside the body of a request using retrofit?

Maybe there's a way to do something like this instead:

```
@POST("/login")
Call<String> login(@MagicTag String email, @MagicTag String hash);
```

I might be missing it from the javadoc from the library, but the website is not very clear when you've never used it. I didn't find any sample using it if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in : http://square.github.io/retrofit/ :

FORM ENCODED AND MULTIPART

Methods can also be declared to send form-encoded and multipart data.

Form-encoded data is sent when @FormUrlEncoded is present on the method. Each key-value pair is annotated with @Field containing the name and the object providing the value.

`@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/user/edit")
Call<User> updateUser(@Field("first_name") String first, @Field("last_name") String last);`

In your case it should be :

`@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
Call<String> login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("hash") String hash);`

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought that @FormUrlEncoded was used to imply add the arguments in the URL and not inside the body in JSON. I'll try ASAP and let you know

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried and it doesn't work. As expected, it is sent to the server as a form and not inside the body of the request.